# Best way to implement few methods from interface in c#

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

We Have following interface which contains some methods.

```
interface MyInterface
{
    string FirstName();
    string LastName();
    string City();
    string Location();
}
```

and this interface we have implemented in our required classes. However, We want to implement Location method only in specific class and not in others. So, which will be the best way to achieve this.

We have tried like below

1. Create Interface with common methods.
2. Create abstract class and implement interface in it
3. Write specific method in abstract class as Virtual
4. Then override the method in actual class

But the problem here is implementation for other method is going in abstract class and not in the implementation class where we wants it.

Whichever the way we are going to achieve this it has to be same for all classes.

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: A couple things: 1) there is not single “best” way; 2) your 'methods' look a lot more like properties; 3) option (1), decoupling into several interfaces, seems the most reasonable.

Comment: Pretty opinion-based, isn´t it? That depends on your use-case and your surroundings.

Comment: The question is a matter of design and depends on use cases, but I don't think it is opinion-based. Once we know the object model, we can talk about the solutions based on references and facts. @HimBromBeere

Comment: Could you please provide us with more information on your object model?

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi Sure, but until that happens this question *is* opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your 'MyInterface' into 2 Interfaces and for all classes you don't want the City method they will implement the one without the city method ,example:

```
    interface MyInterface1
    {
        string FirstName();
        string LastName();
        string City();
    }

    interface MyInterface2 : MyInterface1 
    {
         string Location();
    }
```

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes I did, already updated :)